# Elastic beanstalk ebextensions/config : No package 'libffi' found

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

This is my config :

I only have 2 configs in .ebextensions : 01run.config and 02do.config

.ebextensions/01run.config

```
packages:
    yum:
        python27-devel: ''
        postgresql93-devel: ''
        pkgconfig: ''
        libffi-devel: ''
        libxslt-devel: ''
        libxml2-devel: ''
```

AND this has log , What else should I do ? 
Please help me! Thank you!!

```
  Downloading/unpacking cffi==0.8.6 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 8))
  Running setup.py (path:/opt/python/run/venv/build/cffi/setup.py) egg_info for package cffi
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
```

Comment: Duplicated by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230964/how-to-install-cffi-package-on-aws-beanstalk