# Installing Packages in Elastic Beanstalk (Libffi)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to set up a Flask application on Elastic Beanstalk. One of the dependencies is `cffi`. When I look at the error logs I get the [same error as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230964/how-to-install-cffi-package-on-aws-beanstalk): `Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32696933/2327821) says that libffi needs to installed through a more general package config file for linux packages. So I have the following config file:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    python-dev: []
    python-matplotlib: [] 
    libffi-devel: []
```

However, I am still getting the same error. The config file is named 01run.config and is in .ebextensions/01run.config. How do I check whether these packages are being installed / get them to install?

Comment: You can look at `/var/log/eb-activity.log` to verify that your config file is being processed, and what errors might be occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `eb init` creates a .elasticbeanstalk folder, but it does not create an .ebextensions folder. It was not processing the config file because despite what I wrote I actually had the config file in .elasticbeanstalk rather than .ebextensions.