# Getting Issues and errors while building docker in MacOS-Need HELP to get the docker build and run successfully

Tags: macos, ubuntu, pyarrow, docker-build, python-cffi

I am currently running the code in aws workspace and planning for a transition to run on my MacOS. The docker is well up and running . However, while making changes in the code and making the docker build, getting several errors. Could anyone help in finding a solution so that the docker build can progress without any errors?

As a part of solution, made these following changes:

- Resolved the packages
- Installed the new software – rosetta-softwareupdate --install-rosetta which enables
  Mac with Apple silicon to use apps built for a Mac with an Intel processor
- Used the ubuntu changing from amazonlinux

Here is the latest code for the dockerfile:

```
#FROM public.ecr.aws/amazonlinux/amazonlinux:latest
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV TZ=us/eastern DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
#FROM amazonlinux
ARG pip_username
ARG pip_password

#RUN yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<REPONAME>.sslverify=false
#RUN yum-config-manager --save --setopt=amzn2-core.skip_if_unavailable=true

RUN echo "sslverify=false" >> /etc/yum.conf

#### 

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
#RUN yum install -y python3 awscli jq tar gzip htop make
RUN apt-get install -y python3 awscli jq tar gzip htop make git gcc python3-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev 

RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
#RUN pip3 install opencv-python==4.5.3.56 
WORKDIR /root/python
ADD ./python/requirements.txt requirements.txt
#RUN pip3 install wheel
#RUN pip3 install python3-wheel
#RUN pip3 install setuptools==30.1.0
#RUN pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
#RUN pip3 install numpy
RUN pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt --extra-index-url=https://$pip_username:$pip_password@nexus.ss.arc.travel/repository/pypi-group/simple  
COPY ./python .
COPY ./sql /root/sql
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "src/wrapper.py"]
```

Here is the latest Code for the requirements.txt

```
boto3==1.9.253
botocore==1.12.253
docutils==0.14
jmespath==0.9.4
python-dateutil==2.8.0
s3transfer==0.2.0
six==1.12.0
urllib3==1.24.2
numpy==1.16.2
pyarrow==0.13.0
pandas==0.24.2
pytz==2019.1
unittest-xml-reporting==2.5.1
#asn1crypto==0.24.0
asn1crypto==1.4.0
azure-common==1.1.19
azure-storage-blob==1.5.0
azure-storage-common==1.4.0
certifi==2019.3.9
cffi==1.12.3
chardet==3.0.4
#cryptography==2.6.1
cryptography==36.0.1
future==0.17.1
idna==2.8
ijson==2.3
pyOpenSSL==19.0.0
pycparser==2.19
pycryptodomex==3.8.1
pyjwt==1.7.1
requests==2.21.0
#snowflake-connector-python==1.9.1
snowflake-connector-python==2.7.3
#sqlalchemy==1.3.17
sqlalchemy==1.4.31
#snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.3
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.3.3
pytest==5.3.2
retrying==1.3.3
pyyaml==5.2
pytest-testrail==2.8.3
aenum==2.2.3
aws-xray-sdk==2.5.0

# PDP Nexus Libraries
arc-uuid==1.0.0
pdp-data-events==1.0.3
```

Here is the error screenshot while running-screenshot 1 and then the next part in screenshot 2:

[Error part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RDFG.png)

[Error part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQCgu.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the image is missing libffi-devel (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230964/how-to-install-cffi-package-on-aws-beanstalk)) which is required for the package cffi which in turn is needed for pyarrow.

Unrelated to your issue I would recommend to check your requirements as there are several packages that have much newer and more performant versions (e.g. pyarrow 9.0.0). The viability of bumping versions of course depends on your usage of these packages :)